# Проблема с кодировкой в QT

Tags: c++, qt, кодировка, utf-8, cp1251

Извиняюсь за тавтологию, допущенную ниже, это с целью максимальной понятности. Суть моей программы сводится к тому что она запоминает изменения, произведенные в текстовом файле, сохраняя измененный текст во временный файл temp, а его имя и адрес в файл fn, не изменяя при этом  исходный файл пока пользователь не нажмет соответствующую кнопку или сочетание клавиш.  Скомпилировал программу в Windows 10 и обнаружил, что после закрытия и повторного запуска она некорректно читает содержимое файла fn. Причем, записывается он вполне нормально, то есть, в самом файле fn никаких крокозябр нет. Да и функция открытия файла с ручным выбором файла тоже работает как надо. Я так понимаю, авария происходит где-то на этом этапе: FN=str;  FN - это глобальная переменная QString.
Код, реализующий функцию считывания имени файла и адреса, представлен ниже. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где и как тут прописать виндозовскую кодировку.

Qt Creator 4.14.0
Основан на Qt 5.15.2 (MSVC 2019, 64 бита)

```
//значит, о том, что тут происходит, по порядку. Тут мы вызываем метод QFile по имени name, который читает содержимое файла "fn"
QFile name("fn");
if (!name.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
return;  
QString str;    //объявляем текстовую переменную для хранения пути и имени файла, которые мы собираемся получить в следующей строке
str = name.readAll(); //переменная str получает полное содержимое файла fn из переменной name
FN=str; // Глобальная переменная FN теперь содержит тоже, что и переменная str
statusBar()->showMessage("Открыт файл " + FN); //Выводим сообщение в статус-бар
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> str = name.readAll(); //переменная str получает полное содержимое файла fn из переменной name
> ```

В этой строчке [`readAll()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readAll) возвращает [`QByteArray`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html) с содержимым файла, из которого уже конструируется [`QString`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html). Так вот [`operator=()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#operator-eq-5) присваивая `QString` из `QByteArray` преобразует текст в нём в строку из кодировки `utf8` (для Qt5) аналогично вызову [`QString::fromUtf8()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf8).

В зависимости от конкретной необходимости можно сделать:

- Сохранить файл `fn` в utf-8 и, желательно, явно использовать `QString::fromUtf8()`.
- Сохранить его в локальной кодировке для данной машины и использовать [`QString::fromLocal8bit()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromLocal8Bit). На win с русским языком это обычно `cp1251`.
- Сохранить его в любой заранее выбранной кодировке и открывать его явно в нужной с помощью [`QTextCodec`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html) как-то так:

  ```
  QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("ibm866");
  assert(codec);
  str = codec->toUnicode(name.readAll());
  ```

---

К делу не относится, но дабы избегать подобных ошибок, хорошей практикой является отключение конструкторов `QString` из `QByteArray`/`char*` с помощью объявления [`QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII); и при создании `QString` всегда явно использовать функции вида `fromLocal8Bit`/`Utf8`/`Latin1` и т.п.

Comment: Не ожидал такого быстрого ответа, спасибо вам огромное )

Answer (score 0):

В итоге справился с задачей, ниже код решения:

```
QFile name("fn");
if (!name.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
return;
        QString str;   
        QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("CP1251"); //Вот оно, тут
        assert(codec); // И тут
        str = codec->toUnicode(name.readAll()); // И здесь
        FN=str; // Глобальная переменная FN теперь содержит тоже, что и переменная str
        statusBar()->showMessage("Открыт файл " + FN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, программа изначально задумана под Linux и вроде бы неплохо там работает без свистоплясок с кодировками, поэтому для данного примера я решил уточнить условия компиляции в зависимости от операционной системы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если что, то это примерно и делает `QString::fromLocal8bit()`